# Approximate inverse matrix

Tags: matrices, approximation

Does a method exist to calculate the approximate inverse matrix for a matrix whose elements are small?
To be clearer, let's suppose the elements of the matrix $A$ to be function of a small parameter, i.e. $a_{ij} = a_{ij} (\epsilon)$. Is it possible to obtain the elements of the inverse $A^{-1}$ avoiding to calculate it before and then to study the limit for $\epsilon \rightarrow0$.
For example could we expand the inverse in a series of $\epsilon$ whose terms can be calculated from $A$?

Comment: I forgot to specify that the elements $a_{ij}$ are at most polinomyal function of $\epsilon$ parameter

Comment: Are all of the entries small? Or only some, e.g. the off-diagonal entries?

Comment: If *all* entries arte small you have a problem as you may divide the matri by a small constant ant thus have the equivalent problem of finding the inverse of a matrix with reasonably sized entries. If instead you have that $\lVert A-I\rVert\approx0$, i.e. $A=I-B$ with $B$ small, then $A^{-1}\approx I+B$ (more precisely $A^{-1}=I+B+B^2+B^3+\ldots$ will convereg if $B$ is sufficiently small)

Comment: My matrix is of the form $A=\frac{1}{\epsilon ^2}(I-B(\epsilon))$. Could you tell me where to find references about the method you propose? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

It is in general difficult to compute the inverse of a matrix $A$ when the entries $a_{ij}$ are all near $0$, since the matrix inverse function $A \to A^{-1}$ is so badly behaved as $A \to 0$.  When $A$ is near $0$, $A^{-1}$ becomes *very* large, giving rise to computational instabilities.  This can even be seen when $A$ is $1 \times 1$, by looking at the derivative of the map $x \to x^{-1}$:  if $x$ is a function of some parameter $\epsilon$, $x = x(\epsilon)$, then we have

$\frac{dx^{-1}(\epsilon)}{d\epsilon} = -x^{-2}\frac{dx(\epsilon)}{d\epsilon}$,

showing that $\frac{dx^{-1}(\epsilon)}{d\epsilon}$ can become *very* large even when $\frac{dx(\epsilon)}{d\epsilon}$ is small.  This situation gives rise to numerical errors which become amplified by a factor of $\frac{1}{x^2}$, often severely degrading the accuracy, hence the utility, of approximation methods for $x$ near $0$.  And basically the same thing happens with matrices.  If $A(\epsilon)$ is a parametrized family of matrices, differentiable in $\epsilon$, then we may write

$A^{-1}(\epsilon)A(\epsilon) =  I$,

and taking $\epsilon$-derivatives yields

$\frac{dA^{-1}(\epsilon)}{d\epsilon}A(\epsilon) + A^{-1}(\epsilon)\frac{dA(\epsilon)}{d\epsilon} = 0$,

from which it follows that

$\frac{dA^{-1}(\epsilon)}{d\epsilon} = -A^{-1}(\epsilon)\frac{dA(\epsilon)}{d\epsilon}A^{-1}(\epsilon)$,

and this equation shows that errors in $A(\epsilon)$, as estimated by $\frac{dA(\epsilon)}{d\epsilon}$ via first-order expansion

$A(\epsilon + \Delta \epsilon) \approx A(\epsilon) + \frac{dA(\epsilon)}{d\epsilon}(\Delta \epsilon)$,

will also be subject to a potentially very large "magnification factor" of magnitude roughly
$\vert A^{-1} \vert^2$, where $\vert A^{-1} \vert$ denotes your favorite matrix norm applied to $A^{-1}$:

$A^{-1}(\epsilon + \Delta \epsilon) \approx A^{-1}(\epsilon) + \frac{dA^{-1}(\epsilon)}{d\epsilon}\Delta \epsilon = A^{-1}(\epsilon) - A^{-1}(\epsilon)\frac{dA(\epsilon)}{d\epsilon}A^{-1}(\epsilon)\Delta \epsilon$,

whence

$\vert A^{-1}(\epsilon + \Delta \epsilon) -  A^{-1}(\epsilon) \vert \approx \vert A^{-1}(\epsilon)\frac{dA(\epsilon)}{d\epsilon}A^{-1}(\epsilon)\Delta \epsilon \vert \approx \vert A^{-1} \vert^2 \vert \frac{dA(\epsilon)}{d\epsilon}\Delta \epsilon \vert$.

For these reasons and other, similar ones, people try to avoid computing $A^{-1}$ when
$\vert A \vert$, hence $A$, is small.  What *is* done, however, is to compute approximations to $A^{-1}(\epsilon)$ when *some* of the entries of $A(\epsilon)$ are small.  For example, if we know $A^{-1}(0)$ and we have

$A(\epsilon) = A(0) + (\Delta A)(\epsilon) = A(0)(I + A^{-1}(0)(\Delta A (\epsilon)))$

with

$\vert  A^{-1}(0)(\Delta A (\epsilon)) \vert < 1$,

we can in fact exploit the Neumann series mentioned by Hagen von Eitzen in this comment and 40 votes in his answer to obtain, using the notation $D(\epsilon) =  A^{-1}(0)(\Delta A (\epsilon))$,

$A^{-1}(\epsilon) = (I + D(\epsilon))^{-1}A^{-1}(0) = (I - D(\epsilon) + D^2(\epsilon) - D^3(\epsilon) + . . . )A^{-1}(0)$,

which avoids direct computation of $A^{-1}(\epsilon)$ but replaces it with computing the powers $D^i(\epsilon)$ of $D(\epsilon)$.  This expression will presumably boil down to a power series in $\epsilon$ if $D(\epsilon)$ is sufficiently nice as a function of $\epsilon$, e.g., if $D(\epsilon)$ is analytic in $\epsilon$.

Finally, in your case

$A(\epsilon) = \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}(I - B(\epsilon))$,

you are fortunate in so far as the factor $\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$ is a scalar and can be "pulled out in front" of the matrices.  Thus all you have to do is evaluate the series for

$(I - B(\epsilon))^{-1} = (I + B(\epsilon) + B^2(\epsilon) + B^3(\epsilon) + . . . )$

and multiply the final result by $\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$.  Care must be taken, however, to compute a sufficient number of terms of the above Neumann series for $(I - B(\epsilon))^{-1}$ that a relatively high degree of convergence is obtained; otherwise, when you multiply by $\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$ introduction of severe inaccuracies may occur, as I have (hopefully) explained in the above.

Hope this helps.  Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

The comment by Hagen von Eitzen refers to [Neumann series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series) for the inverse. With $A=\epsilon^{-2}(I-B(\epsilon)$) it takes the form
$$A^{-1}=\epsilon^2 (I+B(\epsilon)+B(\epsilon)^2+B(\epsilon)^3+\dots) \tag1$$
A sufficient condition for the convergence of (1) is $\|B(\epsilon)\|<1$.

The necessary and sufficient condition for the convergence of (1) is $\rho(B(\epsilon))<1$, where $\rho$ is the [spectral radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius).